# Replace white space in png image on transparent background

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, imagemagick, gm

```
operator('Opacity', 'Assign', Math.round( (1 - opacity) * 100 ) + '%')
```

This command from the gm library for node replaces the whole picture.
How I can replace only space with white color on the image with [this lib](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm)?

Comment: This site is for questions, not random code snippets...

Comment: @MarcB i edit question